# Array of Arbitrary Type

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have just started programming in Java again and I am having some trouble. What I want to do is create an object that will be an array of arbitrary dimension. That is it will be an array of arrays of arrays... and so on. What I was thinking of doing was making a class that is an array of arbitrary objects. Thus I could just create the multidimensional array of dimension d by making an array of multidimensional arrays with dimension d-1. The code, I think, would look something like this:

```
Array[] multiArray;

public MArray(int d){
    if(d<0){MArray(d) = null;}
    else{multiArray = MArray(d-1);}
}
```

However I don't know if Array[] is the correct thing to do to create an array of arbitrary objects. I seem to recall when I was learning Java a few years ago there was a way you could it but I can't remember and my Google searches are proving fruitless.

Comment: No, it's `Object[]`. If you test your code with your Java compile, you'll already **know** that `Array[]` is meaningless.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that now. I was getting an error at the Array[] line but I didn't know if it was because it was meaningless or if there was some other problem. Thanks!

Comment: Questions: (a) what is the type of the elements this array is going to hold (in other words: are you going to store integers? strings? alternatively: unknown a-priori but known at compile time? runtime?); (b) do you know (when you create this multi-dim-array) the size of each dimension?

Comment: I am trying to create an object that would be a multidimensional array of integers. The dimensions would probably be known at runtime be not at compile time. That is, I want to be able to call to this object with many different parameters indicating different dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Multidimensional arrays in Java can be created with any Object type(including Object itself). Therefore, you can do a simple declaration like

```
Object[][] my2DimArray = New Object[d-1][d-1]
```